# Slice list of paired strings and integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, subset, slice

I want to subset a list of paired integer and string elements according to the string element found in a list (String_list).

```
String_list = ['I','D','X']

CIG_list = [(65, '='), (1, 'X'), (91, '='), (3, 'D'), (60, '='), (1, 'X'), 
(7, '='), (2, 'S')]
```

I then want to take the sum of the integer elements that precede that element and the integer of that element.

```
    for n in CIG_list:
        if n[1] in String_list:

            hope=CIG_list[0:(CIG_list.index(n)-1)]

            if len(hope) >= 2:
                hope = CIG_list[0:(CIG_list.index(n)-1)]
                hope4=sum([m[0] for m in hope])

            else:
                hope = CIG_list[0:(CIG_list.index(n))]
                hope4=sum([m[0] for m in hope])
```

Best I can tell, this strategy has not worked because the index of the list is not unique (1, 'X') occurs multiple times.

Ideally, I would be able to take the sum of the integers per subset and the string associated where the slice occurred.

Desired Output:

```
[(65, '='), (1, 'X')] , 66 , X
[(65, '='), (1, 'X'), (91, '='), (3, 'D')] , 160 , D
[(65, '='), (1, 'X'), (91, '='), (3, 'D'), (60, '='), (1, 'X')] , 221 , X
```

Comment: How is 129 caculated?

Comment: Incorrect addition on my part (65+1+91+3) = 160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

> **Note:** I've just used the concept of list comprehension & enumerate() function.

```
String_list = ['I','D','X']

CIG_list = [(65, '='), (1, 'X'), (91, '='), (3, 'D'), (60, '='), (1, 'X'), (7, '='), (2, 'S')]

for index, tup in enumerate(CIG_list): 
    ch = CIG_list[index][1]
    if ch in String_list:
        slice_l = CIG_list[:index + 1]             # Used to slice from start to matching point
        total = sum([t[0] for t in slice_l])       # 66, 160, 221 etc.
        last_char = slice_l[-1][1]                 # X, D, X etc.
        print(slice_l, ",", total, ",", last_char) # Print slice_l, total, last_char
```

> Output:

```
[(65, '='), (1, 'X')] , 66 , X
[(65, '='), (1, 'X'), (91, '='), (3, 'D')] , 160 , D
[(65, '='), (1, 'X'), (91, '='), (3, 'D'), (60, '='), (1, 'X')] , 221 , X
```